# Python how to force one string to match format of another

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, formatting

I have a few Python scripts I have written for the Assessor's office where I work.  Most of these ask for an input parcel ID number (this is then used to grab certain data through an odbc).  They are not very consistent about how they input parcel ID's.

So here is my problem, they enter a parcel ID in one of 3 ways:

1: '1005191000060'

2: '001005191000060'

3: '0010-05-19-100-006-0'

The third way is the correct way, so I need to make sure the input is fixed to always match that format.  Of course, they would rather type in the ID one of the first two ways.  The parcel numbers must always be 15 digits long (20 with dashes)

I currently have a working method on how I fix the parcel ID, but it is very ugly.  I am wondering if anyone knows a better way (or a more "Pythonic" way).  I have a function that usually gets imported to all these scripts. Here is what I have:

```
import re

def FormatPID(in_pid):
    pid_format = re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{1}')
    pid = in_pid.zfill(15) 
    if not pid_format.match(pid):
        fixed_pid = '-'.join([pid[:4],pid[4:6],pid[6:8],pid[8:11],pid[11:-1],pid[-1]])
        return fixed_pid
    else:
        return pid

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pid = '1005191000060'
##    pid = '001005191000060'
##    pid = '0010-05-19-100-006-0'

    # test
    t = FormatPID(pid)
    print t
```

This does work just fine, but I have been bothered by this ugly code for a while and I am thinking there has got to be a better way than slicing it.  I am hoping there is a way I can "force" it to be converted to a string to match the "pid_format" variable.  Any ideas?  I couldn't find anything to do this in the regular expressions module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manual slicing you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
import re
from itertools import islice
groups = (4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1)
def FormatPID(in_pid):
    pid_format = re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{1}')
    in_pid = in_pid.zfill(15)
    if not pid_format.match(in_pid):
        it = iter(in_pid)
        return '-'.join(''.join(islice(it, i)) for i in groups)
    return in_pid

print FormatPID('1005191000060')
print FormatPID('001005191000060')
print FormatPID('0010-05-19-100-006-0')
```

**Output:**

```
0010-05-19-100-006-0
0010-05-19-100-006-0
0010-05-19-100-006-0
```

Comment: Lovely...I was trying to find something along the lines of this. I just hated looking at the ugly slice operation I was doing.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't bother using regexes. You just want to get all the digits, ignoring hyphens, left-pad with 0s, then insert the hyphens in the right places, right? So:

```
def format_pid(pid):
    p = pid.replace('-', '')
    if not p.isdigit():
        raise ValueError('Invalid format: {}'.format(pid))
    p = p.zfill(15)
    # You can use your `join` call instead of the following if you prefer.
    # Or Ashwini's islice call.
    return '{}-{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(p[:4], p[4:6], p[6:8], p[8:11], p[11:14], p[14:])
```

Comment: I don't think (s)he wants to do any padding, (s)he wants them to enter the exact digits and then insert the dashes to the appropriate locations.

Comment: @EricAmorde: If he doesn't want to do any padding, how is example #1 going to work?

Comment: Thanks abarnert.  I think I will stick with Eric's answer though.  I was wanting to get away from the "ugly slicing".  This is not so different from my original post. Although, I do like your usage of the isdigit() as opposed to my regex.  Won't my usage of the "\d" do the same thing though?  The documentation says:

Comment: \d
When the UNICODE flag is not specified, matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the set [0-9]. With UNICODE, it will match whatever is classified as a decimal digit in the Unicode character properties database.

Comment: @abarnert: I think I will use the best of both worlds and use your numerical check/error handling with Eric's method to add the dashes using itertools. Now that I think about it, if the user has an extra dash somewhere it will cause an invalid pid exception (if I stick with my regex check) in the other scripts it runs in. Thank you both very much!

Comment: @cmackey: Well, `isdigit()` will do the same thing as a regex explicitly crafted to mean the same thing as `isdigit()`. It'll just be simpler, faster, and much harder to get wrong. But notice that your code is assuming that either you've got all the hyphens in exactly the right place, or you've got nothing but digits; my code is checking that you've got nothing but digits or hyphens, ignoring the hyphens, and using the digits.

Comment: @abarnet.  Yes, that was one critical error I noticed with my code once I saw your isdigit() check; misplaced hyphens would definitely go unnoticed. Thanks for that. I have now changed it to use your method for the first part. Stripping off all hyphens and just accessing the digits as you did and then apply the padding is definitely a huge improvement to what I did.  I feel much better about the code now.  Thanks to both you and Eric for the input!  I always enjoy seeing different techniques.

Comment: @cmackey: Just don't forget to thank Ashwini for the `islice` code. :)

Comment: Ah yes, I gave him the "answwer" and voted up.  I mistakenly said Eric earlier when I meant Ashwini... Thanks to all who helped me out here!  Especially abarnert and Aswhini. I have a long ways to go in my understanding of Python :)

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers are a little over done, imho.

> [rstr](https://pypi.org/project/rstr/) is a helper module for easily generating random strings of
> various types. It could be useful for fuzz testing, generating dummy
> data, or other applications.

```
ASSESSOR_PARCEL = rstr.xeger('^\\d{14}$')
print(ASSESSOR_PARCEL)

>>> 57203112454660
```